# Transpose column into row based on the new line

Tags: awk, xargs

I have file like this

```
d
e
e

s
k

a
b
c
d
```

I just need to convert then as like this

```
dee
sk
abcd
```

For this purpose I used awk and xargs

```
xargs < file|awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}'
```

But it is not generating results as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS='' '{$1=$1}1' file

dee
sk
abcd
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
!NF && value{
  print value
  value=""
  next
}
NF{
  value=value $0
}
END{
  if(value){
     print value
  }
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -0pe 's/\n(?=.)//g' file
```

## Output

```
dee
sk
abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -l -00pe 'y/\n//d' file
```

`-00` is similar to `awk -v RS=`